# using group by and max on columns remove repeat value just get Maximum id value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'group_get_max' using group by and max on column and I want to remove repeat value just get Maximum id value, How can I do?

this is my table.

```
SELECT * FROM for_test.group_get_max;
```

**output**

```
+----+--------------+----------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| Id | warehouse_id | goods_id | price | inc  | quantity | operated_at |
+----+--------------+----------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 |            1 |        2 |   100 |   50 |       50 | 2020-03-21  |
|  2 |            1 |        2 |   100 |   50 |      150 | 2020-03-22  |
|  3 |            1 |        2 |   100 |   50 |      100 | 2020-03-21  |
|  4 |            1 |        2 |   100 |   50 |      150 | 2020-03-23  |
|  5 |            1 |        2 |   100 |   50 |      200 | 2020-03-23  |
|  6 |            1 |        3 |   100 |  100 |      100 | 2020-03-21  |
|  7 |            1 |        3 |   100 |   50 |      150 | 2020-03-22  |
|  8 |            1 |        3 |   100 |   50 |      200 | 2020-03-22  |
|  9 |            1 |        3 |   100 |   50 |      200 | 2020-03-23  |
| 10 |            1 |        3 |   100 |   50 |      250 | 2020-03-23  |
| 11 |            1 |        3 |   100 |   50 |      250 | 2020-03-21  |
| 12 |            1 |        2 |   100 |   50 |      200 | 2020-03-22  |
+----+--------------+----------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The following is the query to use GROUP BY and MAX columns −

```
SELECT 
    group_get_max.goods_id, group_get_max.warehouse_id,
    group_get_max.quantity,group_get_max.operated_at,group_get_max.id
FROM
    group_get_max
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        group_get_max.warehouse_id,
            group_get_max.goods_id,
            MAX(group_get_max.operated_at) AS operated_at
    FROM
        group_get_max
    WHERE
        group_get_max.operated_at <  '2020-03-23'
            AND group_get_max.warehouse_id IN ('1' , '2', '3')
    GROUP BY group_get_max.goods_id , group_get_max.warehouse_id) AS q 
       ON group_get_max.operated_at = q.operated_at
        AND q.warehouse_id = group_get_max.warehouse_id
        AND q.goods_id = group_get_max.goods_id
WHERE
    group_get_max.warehouse_id IN ('1', '2','3')
```

**After this query, I will get these data**

```
+----------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+
| goods_id | warehouse_id | quantity | operated_at | id |
+----------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+
|        2 |            1 |      200 | 2020-03-22  | 12 |
|        2 |            1 |      150 | 2020-03-22  |  2 |
|        3 |            1 |      200 | 2020-03-22  |  8 |
|        3 |            1 |      150 | 2020-03-22  |  7 |
+----------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+
```

**But I just want to get max id after group by.**

```
+----------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+
| goods_id | warehouse_id | quantity | operated_at | id |
+----------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+
|        3 |            1 |      200 | 2020-03-22  |  8 |
|        2 |            1 |      200 | 2020-03-22  | 12 |
+----------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+
```

**How can I do? I'm waiting online**

Comment: I think you could better of using a sort and limit to find the latest date.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Can you give me an example of one?

Comment: `SELECT operated_at FROM group_get_max ORDER BY operated_at LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a join use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT g.* FROM group_get_max AS g
WHERE g.operated_at < '2020-03-23' AND g.warehouse_id IN ('1' , '2', '3')
AND g.Id = (
  SELECT Id FROM group_get_max
  WHERE warehouse_id = g.warehouse_id AND goods_id = g.goods_id
  AND operated_at < '2020-03-23' AND warehouse_id IN ('1' , '2', '3')
  ORDER BY operated_at DESC, quantity DESC 
  LIMIT 1
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szcwUwecg2xFHpfLgBPLYj/0).
For MySql 8.0+ you can use `row_number()` window function:

```
SELECT 
  t.Id, t.warehouse_id, t.goods_id, 
  t.price, t.inc, t.quantity, t.operated_at
FROM (  
  SELECT *, 
    row_number() over (partition by warehouse_id, goods_id order by operated_at DESC, quantity DESC) rn
  FROM group_get_max
  WHERE operated_at < '2020-03-23' AND warehouse_id IN ('1' , '2', '3')
) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szcwUwecg2xFHpfLgBPLYj/1).
Results:

```
| Id  | warehouse_id | goods_id | price | inc | quantity | operated_at  |
| --- | ------------ | -------- | ----- | --- | -------- | ------------ |
| 8   | 1            | 3        | 100   | 50  | 200      | 2020-03-22   |
| 12  | 1            | 2        | 100   | 50  | 200      | 2020-03-22   |
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it.